# How can I navigate to a nested stack screen inside a sibling tab while preserving its initial screen? (React Navigation)

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-navigation-v6

#### The Code:

I'm using React Navigation 6 with the following hierarchy:

```
MainTabNavigator
    HomeStack
        HomeScreen (HomeStack initial screen, contains a "Pay" button)
        OtherScreen
    MembershipStack
        MembershipHomeScreen (MembershipStack initial screen)
        PayMembershipScreen (should always navigate back to MembershipHomeScreen)
```

The App launches into `HomeScreen` (inside `HomeStack`), so the `MembershipStack` tab **won't** be loaded yet.

There is a "Pay" button inside `HomeScreen` that redirects to `PayMembershipScreen` inside `MembershipStack`.

Code of the `HomeScreen` with the "Pay" button press handler:

```js
const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    const payPressHandler = useCallback(() => {
        // The parent navigator here is MainTabNavigator
        navigation.getParent().navigate("MembershipStack", { screen: "PayMembershipScreen" })
    }, [navigation])

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={payPressHandler}>
            <Text>Go to Pay screen!</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

The "Pay" button inside `HomeScreen` does navigate to `PayMembershipScreen` with this code.

#### The Problem:

When the `MembershipStack` tab has not yet been loaded (i.e. when the App just launched), the following happens:

1. User clicks the "Pay" button on `HomeScreen`.
2. App navigates to `PayMembershipScreen`.
3. `PayMembershipScreen` *becomes the initial screen* on `MembershipStack`.
4. User can't go back to `MembershipHomeScreen` from `PayMembershipScreen`.

The question is: how can I navigate from `HomeScreen` directly to `PayMembershipScreen` and after that be able to **go back to** `MembershipHomeScreen` (i.e. have it available as the initial screen in the `MembershipStack` history)?

#### What I've tried so far:

*1. Setting `lazy: false` on the `MainTabNavigator` options.*

This approach does make sure that `MembershipHomeScreen` is always the initial screen on `MembershipStack`, since all stacks (and their initial screens) will be loaded when the App launches. *However* this comes with a noticeable drawback in performance, since there's at least 5 tabs in the actual project.

Also, since `MembershipHomeScreen` is already focused inside `MembershipStack`, there's a weird `MembershipHomeScreen` to `PayMembershipScreen` transition animation when the "Pay" button on `HomeScreen` is pressed. I just want the user to see a transition from `HomeScreen` to `PayMembershipScreen` *at most*, nothing flashing inbetween.

---

*2. Define a param on `MembershipHomeScreen` to indicate when I want to redirect to `PayMembershipScreen`.*

On this approach, I'm using a boolean param on `MembershipHomeScreen` called **redirectToPayment**:

Code inside `MembershipHomeScreen`:

```js
const MembershipHomeScreen = ({navigation, route}) => {
    const { redirectToPayment = false } = route.params

    const redirectIfNeeded = useCallback(() => {
        if (redirectToPayment) {
            // reset the param
            navigation.setParams({ redirectToPayment: false })
            // redirect to the desired screen
            navigation.navigate("PayMembershipScreen")
        }
    }, [redirectToPayment, navigation])

    // Using layout effect to avoid rendering MembershipHomeScreen when redirecting.
    useLayoutEffect(redirectIfNeeded)

    return (
        <Text>
            This is just the membership home screen,
            not the target screen of the "Pay" button.
        </Text>
    )
}
```

And on the `HomeScreen`:

```js
const payPressHandler = useCallback(() => {
    navigation
        .getParent()
        .navigate(
            "MembershipStack",
            { screen: "MembershipHomeScreen", params: { redirectToPayment: true } }
        )
}, [navigation])
```

The use of React's `useLayoutEffect` comes with the known drawback of *freezing* the screen since it will leave any rendering tasks on hold while it's running. I'm able to notice a *2 seconds* freeze in the `HomeScreen` when I press the "Pay" button on a 4GB RAM Moto G7...

...and even after using `useLayoutEffect`, the `MembershipHomeScreen` still renders nonetheless to show a transition animation between `MembershipHomeScreen` and `PayMembershipScreen`.

Same behavior with `useEffect`, except it renders the `MembershipHomeScreen` instead of a 2 seconds freeze.

---

*3. Using React Navigation's `dispatch` function to customize the route history.*

On this approach, I intend to dispatch a [custom action](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#custom-action-creators) that does the following to the navigation state of `MainTabNavigator`:

**Before:**

```js
index: 0
routes: [
    0: {
        name: "HomeStack",
        state: {
            index: 0,
            routes: [
                0: {
                    name: "Home" // <-- currently active screen
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    1: {
        name: "MembershipStack",
        state: undefined // <-- this is an unloaded tab
    }
]
```

**After:**

```js
index: 1
routes: [
    0: {
        name: "HomeStack",
        state: {
            index: 0,
            routes: [
                0: {
                    name: "Home"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    1: {
        name: "MembershipStack",
        state: {
            index: 1,
            routes: [
                0: {
                    name: "MembershipHomeScreen"
                },
                1: {
                    name: "PayMembershipScreen" // <-- currently active screen
                }
            ]
        }
    },
]
```

Here's the code I'm using inside the `HomeScreen` for that:

```js
const payPressHandler = useCallback(() => {

        navigation.getParent().dispatch(state => {
            const membershipTabIndex = state.routes.findIndex(r => r.name === "MembershipStack")

            // get the current navigation state inside the MembershipStack
            let membershipTabState = state.routes[membershipTabIndex].state

            // point to PayMembershipScreen without overriding the initial screen on that tab
            if (!membershipTabState) {
                // tab is unloaded, so just set the ideal state
                membershipTabState = { index: 1, routes: [{ name: "MembershipHomeScreen" }, { name: "PayMembershipScreen" }] }
            } else {
                // tab already has a navigation state, so we'll point to PayMembershipScreen 
                // if it's loaded in the stack. Otherwise, we'll add it and point to it.
                let payMembershipScreenIndex = membershipTabState.routes.findIndex(r => r.name === "PayMembershipScreen")

                if (payMembershipScreenIndex === -1) {
                    payMembershipScreenIndex = membershipTabState.routes.push({ name: "PayMembershipScreen" }) - 1
                }

                membershipTabState.index = payMembershipScreenIndex
            }

            // update the MembershipStack tab with the new state
            const routes = state.routes.map((r, i) => i === membershipTabIndex ? { ...r, state: membershipTabState} : r)

            // update the MainTabNavigator state
            return CommonActions.reset({
                ...state,
                routes,
                index: membershipTabIndex
            })
        })
}, [navigation])
```

That code almost accomplishes the expected outcome:

- It navigates from `HomeScreen` to `PayMembershipScreen` successfuly.
- The user can go back to `MembershipHomeScreen` from `PayMembershipScreen`.
- `MembershipHomeScreen` does not render in-between during the transition.

However:

- It won't work a *second time* if you do go back to `MembershipHomeScreen` from `PayMembershipScreen`.

Turns out, if I go back to `MembershipHomeScreen` once I'm inside `PayMembershipScreen`, then go back to the `HomeStack` and press the "Pay" button again, it will now navigate to *`MembershipHomeScreen` instead of `PayMembershipScreen`*.

Additionally, the `MembershipHomeScreen` will now display a *disabled* back button in the header (probably a bug).

This last approach is so far **the closest** to getting the desired outcome, so I really hope that it only needs a fix in the logic and it's not really a bug.

---

#### Summary:

Is anyone able find a solution that achieves the expected outcome? To sum up:

- It should make the "Pay" button navigate from `HomeScreen` to `PayMembershipScreen`.
- The user should be able to go back to `MembershipHomeScreen` once they're in `PayMembershipScreen`.
- The `MembershipHomeScreen` should not flash in the transition from `HomeScreen` to `PayMembershipScreen`.
- The screen should not freeze inbetween the transitions (no use of `useLayoutEffect`).
- Don't load all tabs on App launch (it's too much burden on the actual 5-tab project).
- If the user navigates back to `MembershipHomeScreen` once they're in`PayMembershipScreen`, pressing the "Pay" button on `HomeScreen` again should open the `PayMembershipScreen` again (no buggy behavior).

#### Minimal reproducible example:

Here's a snack with all of the approaches mentioned. Please check it out and use it as a playground for your solution!

https://snack.expo.dev/@ger88555/tabs-with-stacks-and-a-button

Comment: Have you tried `initialRouteName` prop in Stack?

Comment: Yes, `MembershipStack` has "MembershipHomeStack" explicitly set as the `initialRouteName`

Comment: I added the link to a snack so you can see it in action, sorry for not doing it earlier when I posted the question. Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get your solution to work for me.
Instead, I used a version of your proposed remedy #2, except that inside of the intermediary screen (which would be `MembershipHomeScreen` in your example, I used `useEffect`, looked for the parameter that I had specified in the previous screen (`HomeScreen`, in your example), and then called `navigation.push()`, rather than `navigation.navigate()`.  Note that `push()` is only available when the navigator is a `StackNavigator`.  The parameters are the same, though.

There is a quick flash of the intermediary screen, but no freeze.  Although, it should be noted that in my case, the intermediary screen is very lightweight, with no effects other than logging a Google Analytics event asynchronously.

HomeScreen:

```
const payPressHandler = () => {
    navigation.navigate("MembershipStack", 
        {
            screen: "MembershipHomeScreen", 
            params: {
                navToNested: {
                    name: 'PayMembershipScreen',
                    params: {
                        customParamForDestinationScreen: 'foo'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

MembershipHomeScreen:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (route?.params?.navToNested) {
        const navTo = route.params.navToNested;
        navigation.push(navTo.name, navTo.params);
    }
}, [route]);
```

This still doesn't feel like the cleanest, most ideal solution, but it works, more or less.  It is what I am using in my own app for now.  Hopefully, it is of some help to the original poster, or to others who read this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you state, this solution is ideal when you don't mind the intermediary screen flashing in the transition and/or it doesn't have much logic. Regarding the solution from the other answer that did not work for you, what version of React Navigation are you using? Did you run the Snack from the link?

Comment: Hi @Okkult. I ran the snack on the web and in the iOS emulator available on the snack's web page. It worked fine. I couldn't get that method to work in my project, but that might very well be because of some quirk in my project.

In my project, I have the following dependencies related to navigation:
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.3",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.7.0"

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

I got the expected outcome with the following approach:

- Navigate directly to `PayMembershipScreen` when the "Pay" button is pressed.
- Inside `PayMembershipScreen`, add `MembershipHomeScreen` to the top of `MembershipStack` history if not already present.

#### The Code

Code inside `HomeScreen` (no changes):

```js
const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    const payPressHandler = useCallback(() => {
        navigation.getParent().navigate("MembershipStack", { screen: "PayMembershipScreen" })
    }, [navigation])

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={payPressHandler}>
            <Text>Go to Pay screen!</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

New `useAssertInitialScreen` hook:

```js
const useAssertInitialScreen = ({ navigation, name }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (navigation.canGoBack() === false) {
            navigation.dispatch((state) => {
                const routes = [{ name }, ...state.routes]
    
                return CommonActions.reset({
                    ...state,
                    routes,
                    index: state.index + 1
                })
            })
        }
    }, [navigation])
}
```

Note: I'm passing the `navigation` prop down the hook since it's also used in the screen, but it could also be obtained from React Navigation's `useNavigation` hook.

Code inside `PayMembershipScreen`:

```js
const PayMembershipScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    
    useAssertInitialScreen({ navigation, name: "MembershipHomeScreen" })

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>
                This is the PayMembershipScreen AKA the target
            </Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

#### Demo

Here's a snack with the code of this answer:

https://snack.expo.dev/@ger88555/tabs-with-stacks-and-a-button---a-solution

---

I still want to see whether there's a *cleaner* solution than handling the "Pay" button's functionality inside its target screen.

##### I'll mark as the accepted answer any other solution that gets the expected outcome :)